# RcDevice Error: Time Out waiting on Register in restcomm

Tags: android, jain-sip, restcomm

I am new in restcomm, in example of restcomm-helloworld i was only change in ip

```
params.put("pref_proxy_domain", "sip:192.168.1.119:5082");
params.put("pref_sip_user", "bob");
params.put("pref_sip_password", "1234");
device = RCClient.createDevice(params, this);
```

in **android** and i got that error.

i used local ip address for register please tell any change in android side or server side?

On that local ip web application perfectly working.

Comment: Hi Pratik, what error are you getting in Android logcat? Also, I assume you are using restcomm server as the SIP server, right? If so the port you use should probably be 5080 not 5082. 5082 is usually for websocket, not sip over tcp that android uses.

Comment: thanks **atsakiridis**  it's working i change port number 5082 to 5080, but i need to more R&D of this subject to understand.

Comment: Lost you Pratik, what do you need? If you want to get started you can have a look at the Restcomm Android SDK quick start guide at http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/sdks/restcomm-client-android-sdk-quick-start.html#android-sdk-guide. You should find all the needed resources there

Comment: thank you i try to open restcomm-olympus i got error no such class **import org.webrtc.CameraEnumerationAndroid**  and **import org.webrtc.voiceengine.WebRtcAudioManager** in PeerConectionClient.java file  and how do i get letest sdk for android